# using the case statement to find an index and return it

Tags: ruby, median, case-statement

After playing about with this all morning(i am still new to this), I have decided to ask the experts.

This is the quest:

You are going to be given a word. 
Your job is to return the middle character of the word. 
If the word's length is odd, return the middle character. 
If the word's length is even, return the middle 2 characters.

This is what I have so far:

```rb
def median(string)                           
      array = string.split(//) 
      case array
      when array.length == 1  
        return array[0]
      when array.length == 2
        return array[0] + array[1]                
      when array.length.odd? && array.length >= 3                   
        return array[(array.length - 1) / 2] 
      when array.length.even? && array.length >= 4              
        return array[((array.length / 2 ) - 1)] + array[(array.length / 2)]
        else nil
      end
end



puts median("testing")
```

what is wrong with my code. It runs but delivers nothing. Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: The problem is your (mis-)usage of case/when. Use if/elsif instead. And read up on where and for what case/when _should_ be used.

Comment: your case statement should be `case array.length` and the when statements should be `when 1`

Comment: @TallPaul: how do you propose to handle the last two cases then?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree with your statement, I just wanted to point out how in general he would want to do a case statement

Comment: I appreciate both inputs guys, obviously I do need to read up the case statement. The response from posting this was better than I had hoped. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `array` from the line `case array`. I only did this change to your code and it [works just fine](http://ideone.com/chUhfR):

```rb
def median(string)                           
  array = string.split(//) 
  case
  when array.length == 1  
    return array[0]
  when array.length == 2
    return array[0] + array[1]                
  when array.length.odd? && array.length >= 3                   
    return array[(array.length - 1) / 2] 
  when array.length.even? && array.length >= 4              
    return array[((array.length / 2 ) - 1)] + array[(array.length / 2)]
  else nil
  end
end
```

In the initial version of the code, having `case array` meant that on each branch Ruby would compare the "when" value (which is always a boolean value) to array, which is never boolean, therefore never equal to any of the branches. this is why the `else nil` branch was always the exit point of the `case` block.

Changing `case array` to `case` will tell Ruby that it does not need to performa  comparison, but to evaluate each branch condition and execute the first one that is true.

---

This being said, your code can be simplified in a few ways:

- there's no need to convert the string to an array; string indexing would work just fine in this case
- the conditions `&& array.length >= 3` and `&& array.length >= 4` are superfluous; a lower value would hit the `array.length == 1` or `array.length == 2` branches
- the `array.length == 1` or `array.length == 2` branches are really not that special; you can just treat them in the odd/even length cases.

Applying these considerations I ended up with this code, which also [works OK](http://ideone.com/fZgFd9):

```rb
def word_median(word)
  half = word.length / 2

  case
  when word == '' then ''
  when word.length.odd? then word[half]
  else word[half - 1..half]
  end
end
```

Comment: "or array.length == 2 branches are really not that special" - this bullet point contradicts the previous one. :)

Comment: thanks wolf, you went overboard there. I downloaded the tests you made. I had no idea I could range an index to get both values, even more amazed to realise I could apply those methods to a string! The code looks slimmer now, just as it should be, refined down to its finest point.